# We have no [press], [press-release], [popular-press], [public-relations], [publicity] tags even though these are regularly leveraged by universities

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Major universities frequently have departments and staff and web pages for press releases related to notable ("hot") publications by faculty. They make sure that the popular press has the news in a pre-digested press-release form, a bit of biographical info on their faculty and a link to the actual publication. When paywalled there are often specially licensed links to viewable but not downloadable pdfs.

Interaction with the popular press is now an academic activity, benefitting both faculty and the university, and in an indirect way, funding agencies, i.e. 'this is your tax dollars hard at work'.

I searched for tags like [press], [press-release], [popular-press], [public-relations], and [publicity] for my new question [How popular scientific news & Google get doi links leading to zombie pages when first release, but later, do link to the intended scientific paper?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/204200/69206) but couldn't find anything.

Is it time to recognize the publicity aspect of academic research by including some kind of tag? Is there one already but I just failed to find it perhaps due to lack of sufficient synonymization?

---

Here are some examples of questions that relate to press-releases, writing about academic research in the popular press, and citing the popular press.

[@Anyon points out](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5386/69206) that the [self-promotion](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-promotion) tag exists (35 instances since 2012), and I think a lot of these questions deserve that tag but don't currently have it.

But I think this quickly assembled partial list suggests there is a body of questions related to the popular press and press releases.

If there's some agreement of some kind of "press" tag, then a retagging effort might be considered for it (and for the underutilized [self-promotion](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-promotion). I've participated in several, you do it in small batches over time so as not to overwhelm the active question queue.

- [How to get covered in non-academic media](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/46470/69206)
- [Should you include press interviews and articles about your work in your CV?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/44809/69206)
- [Do my articles published in local newspapers count as publications?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/77681/69206)
- [How to contact journalists for a press release in the UK?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/171616/69206)
- [What’s included in a press kit for a research project?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/109305/69206)
- [Where can I publish summaries of my research?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/64479/69206)
- [How to write a scholarship press release?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/11910/69206)
- [Are technical news websites acceptable as references in the introduction or motivation section?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/120457/69206)
- [Referencing someone else's Appendix with news articles URLs, or putting the links in my own appendix?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/166488/69206)
- [Can my institute use my figure and put their name on it for press releases, etc.?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/37791/69206)
- [APA citation of a published interview](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/67232/69206)
- [Should I cite the interviewer or the interviewee when citing a news article?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/58337/69206)
- [Does social media and mainstream presence, through interviews and publishing in the "trade press", help one's chances at tenure?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/111504/69206)
- [Should you include press interviews and articles about your work in your CV?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/44809/69206)
- [Measuring the Effect of Public Relations on Scientific Journals Impact Factor?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/79034/69206)
- [Are (academic) job chances improved by extra-academic activities (Podcast, Popular Science Books)?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/87518/69206)
- [Citing a popular science magazine article](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/88979/69206)
- [Does Pop-Science involvement hurt one's reputation?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/285/69206)

Comment: Can you find a substantial number of existing questions that would be appropriately labeled with a given tag that would help organize them together for a person who has a specific interest in that area of academia? If so, I'd present that list and suggest creation of the tag. Otherwise it seems we don't need it, even if it could plausibly be useful.

Comment: Some such questions have been classified under [tag:self-promotion].

Comment: @BryanKrause Sure, I have extensive experience with that kind of search (e.g. [1](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/703/7982), [2](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/614/7982)) and ok I'll do it here. *But it takes a day or so* to do well. I will point out that lack of the tag may discourage questions, so there may be some bias involved.

Comment: @Anyon that's actually worthy of being an answer post in order to alert folks of its existence. It's not a perfect fit (since the promotion machinery of a university goes beyond self-promotion of one's own research) but it's in the right direction.

Comment: I doubt lack of tag affects whether questions are asked. Tag selection seems an afterthought to most posters. They are more important on SO since the site is so massive.

Comment: @BryanKrause we only know how we ask our own questions, we have no insight into what goes on in other people's minds, though we might imagine we do. I am probably a much more active question-asker than you and I always pay attention to available tags as a hint to what may or may not fly as on-topic in a site, especially if it's a site I'm less active on.

Comment: @uhoh Your extensive experience asking questions on the site makes you quite unusual - most askers are relatively new and ask few questions. I'm basing my thoughts not on my own posting but the design of the ask a question page and the quality of tagging that people do.

Comment: @BryanKrause the metric that counts is not the number of users, but the number of questions posted where tags were referred to as part of the process, so I get a multiplier that makes my questions less unusual than me. But point well taken.

Comment: @BryanKrause Done! I've added at least a partial list. As an aside it seems many folks did indeed fail to notice the self-promotion tag which has been there since 2012, further confirming that I'm not normal :-)

Answer (score 1):

The tag [self-promotion](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-promotion) is applicable to some such questions, perhaps not ones pertaining to institutional or organizational perspectives, but at least ones pertaining to an academic drafting a press release on their own work. A small number of relevant questions have received this tag, for example

- [How to write a scholarship press release?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/11910/17254)
- [How to get published research covered by science magazines so as to promote the research among the community?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/173383/17254)

However, some are simply tagged [publications](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publications)

- [How to get covered in non-academic media](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/46470/17254)
- [How to contact journalists for a press release in the UK?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/171616/17254)

Comment: @uhoh encouraged turning my comment into an answer, so here it is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer post! Note: I'm finding many examples, many of which could use the self-promotion tag but didnt, and I'll add them to my question soon. I guess we need to promote the self-promotion tag better :-)